# Log on as a service vs Log on as a batch job

Tags: .net, iis, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, application-pool

I've created service account to host an IIS web app pool.

I know IIS will be happy if I grant both `Log on as a service` and `Log on as a batch job` permissions, but I suspect one is unnecessary.

I have been able to find any official documentation on exactly which one is required.

What is the difference? And are both required to host an IIS App Pool?

Answer (score 2):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat

As long as your pool identity is added to IIS_IUSRS group by IIS itself, you have no need to change any user rights assignments.